# How to construct communication between server and client for Android Application that uses Database

Tags: java, android, web-services, network-programming

I need to develop an application that communicates with the server. I am not new to Android, but I have never developed a program that uses server/client communication.

Basically, I am planning to store my databse in the server and this server takes query from the client and then returns the result back. How can I send query from client to server ? How can I take the resulting data bacik in client ?

I do not know what kind of connection/protocol should I use. Can you suggest me any book ? Or if there is someone who is experienced in this subject, can give me advice ? What should be my starting point ?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

It's called RPC - remote procedure call. There are many different protocols and implementations. You should pick one that works over HTTP (as this pretty much works on any network).

Try XML-RPC or JSON-RPC:

Some starting points:

http://code.google.com/p/android-json-rpc/

http://oss.metaparadigm.com/jsonrpc/

http://code.google.com/p/android-xmlrpc/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML-RPC#Java